# Select where I only have the last 3 numbers of a column. how do I select from that table?

Tags: sql-server

I need to do a select from a column named cGLsubaccount in a table where the numbers in that column are 9 numbers long (eg 010009143). The problem I have is that I have a string which contains the resultset from another table and the string contains 3 numbers each (eg 143,275,684,955). These numbers correspond to the last three numbers of the column cGLsubaccount. How do I write a sql statement to select from the table where the last 3 numbers of cGLsubaccount matches the numbers in the list? if you could show me how to write the sql statement for say 143, It would help me out. I tried

```
select cName, cGLsubaccount
from HOUSE
where cGLsubaccount like %123%
```

but it didn't work. I need your help guys. (The database is SQL-Server 2012 I believe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
select cName, cGLsubaccount
from HOUSE
where Right(cGLsubaccount,3) = @string
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It does exactly what I need!

Comment: @Tettah Excellent!

Answer (score 1):

Rather than one at a time, you could query the entire list in one shot.

```
Declare @String varchar(max)='143,275,684,955'

Select cName, cGLsubaccount
From   HOUSE A
Join  (
        Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
              ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
        From (Select x = Cast('<x>'+ Replace(@String,',','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
        Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
      ) B
 On cGLsubaccount Like '%'+RetVal
```

FYI - the sub-query returns

```
RetSeq  RetVal
1       143
2       275
3       684
4       955
```

Comment: @Tetteh Happy to help.